# DDMathParser implicit multiplication not working

Tags: swift3, ddmathparser

I use DDMathParser to solver formula expressions using Swift. The following code works fine, however, implicit multiplication doesn't. Reading the [docs](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Implicit-Multiplication) it should work... So, what do I miss here?
my code:

```
...
substitutions.updateValue(3, forKey: "x")
let myString = "3$x"

    do{
        let expression = try Expression(string: myString, operatorSet: operatorSet, options: myTRO, locale: myLocale)
        let result = try evaluator.evaluate(expression, substitutions: substitutions)
        print("expression is: \(expression), the result is : \(result)")
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
...
```

The code throws the "Error". Using the string `"3*$x"` the expression is calculated as expected.

Comment: Huh... that seems like it should parse... what’s the specific error you’re catching?

Comment: @DaveDeLong, the error thrown is an `invalidFormat` error.

Answer (score 1):

DDMathParser author here.

So, the `.invalidFormat` error is thrown when the framework has a sequence of tokens and is looking for an operator in order to figure out what goes around it. If it can't find an operator but still has tokens to resolve but no operator, then it throws the `.invalidFormat` error.

This implies that you have a `3.0` number token and a `$x` variable token, but no `×` multiplication token.

I see also that you're passing in a custom set of `TokenResolverOptions` (the `myTRO` variable). I'd guess that you're passing in an option set that does *not* include the `.allowImplicitMultiplication` value. If I try to parse `3$x` *without* the `.allowImplicitMultiplication` resolver option, then I get the `.invalidFormat` error thrown.

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks for the response. How do I actually include the `.allowImplicitMultiplication`

Comment: @JFS how are you creating the `myTRO` variable? The default options include implicit multiplication

Comment: I simply do the following: `let myTRO = TokenResolverOptions()` without adding something to the myTRO so far.

Comment: I don't want to change/add something to the `operatorSet` nor to the `options` but I need to use this advanced expression definition in order to work with localized expression strings.

Comment: Oh, using `let expression = try Expression(string: myString)` is working with implicit multiplication! But than I can't us the localized expression string option...

Comment: where can I find more details about how to use localized expression strings? I think there are so many options and functions within `DDMathParser` but the wiki is a little modest...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it myself. As Dave DeLong mentioned `.allowImplicitMultiplication` is included by default in the options but will get ignored when creating custom `options`. Since I want to use localized expressions (decimal separator within expression string is local) I need to use the advanced definition of `Expression`:

```
let expression = try Expression(string: ..., operatorSet: ..., options: ..., locale: ...)
```

In order to use the localized string option I defined `let myLocale = NSLocale.current` but accidentally also created a new `operatorSet` new `options` and passed it to the expression definition. The right way is not to create custom `operatorSet` and `options` but to use the defaults within the `Expression` definition:

```
let expression = try Expression(string: expressionString, operatorSet: OperatorSet.default, options: TokenResolverOptions.default, locale: myLocale)
```

Dave DeLong did a really great job in creating the `DDMatParser` framework. For newbies it is very hard to get started with. The [wiki](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki) section at `DDMathParser` is pretty basic and doesn't give some details or examples for all the other great functionality `DDMatParser` is providing.